# SQL: checking duplicates with/without leading zeroes

Tags: sql, leading-zero

I need to find same items duplicated in a database with/without a leading zero. Examples:
[image]

You can see my query below but it doesn't find the items with the issue:

```
SELECT A.LOCID, B.LOCID2
FROM (
    SELECT LOCID
    FROM TABLENAME
    WHERE regexp_like( LOCID, '^[[:digit:]]*$') -- LOCID only digital characters
    AND LOCID LIKE '0%'
    )AS A
inner join (
    --SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM LOCID ) AS LOCID2
    SELECT LOCID AS LOCID2
    FROM TABLENAME
    WHERE LOCID NOT LIKE '0%'
    and regexp_like( LOCID, '^[[:digit:]]*$')
    )  AS B
ON A.LOCID = B.LOCID2;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Does that sample data really represent actual table data? One column without a leading zero, and another column with the same value just a leading zero?

Comment: Relational db, working with SQL. YES, my IDs are very similar to these and the issue is that they represent the same item/row but where uploaded in the system sometimes with/without the leading zero. We would need to find the list and clean the wrong rows/items.

Comment: @Ana, is it Oracle?

Comment: No, I work in an internal application with SQL.

Comment: There are dozens of different SQL databases, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems, and string handling and regexp are typically vendor specific.

Comment: Convert to int then back to char.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` function to remove leading zeros e.g.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('00010011', '^(0*)', '\2');
```

which yields `10011`. So you can join on the replaced ids rather than actual ones.

You can test it with this:

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['001230', '022']) a inner join 
UNNEST(ARRAY['1230', '0220', '222', '00']) b on 
REGEXP_REPLACE(a, '^(0*)', '\2') = REGEXP_REPLACE(b, '^(0*)', '\2');
```

This gives you:

```
a,      b
001230, 1230
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Oracle, so here is an Oracle solution. Rather than using regexp_replace to look for digits only, you could compare upper() to lower() assuming that letters are the only other values in this column.

Multiple ways to accomplish this, including using a CTE to get two columns.

This should work with many different DBMS'. You may just need to modify `substr` or `length` to match your system.

```
create table TABLENAME (
  LOCID varchar(20)
  );
```

```
insert all
 into tablename (LOCID) values ('100123')
 into tablename (LOCID) values ('0100123')
 into tablename (LOCID) values ('100222')
 into tablename (LOCID) values ('0123')
 into tablename (LOCID) values ('123')
 into tablename (LOCID) values ('0100222z')
Select 1 from dual;
```

```
select locid, locid2
from (
    with cte as (
      select locid,  
      case 
       when substr(locid, 1, 1) = '0' then substr(locid, 2, length(locid) - 1) 
       else locid 
      end locid2
    from tablename
    where upper(locid) = lower(locid)
    )
    select locid, locid2, 
       row_number() over (partition by locid2 order by locid desc) as rn
    from cte
)z
where rn = 2
```

| LOCID | LOCID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0100123 | 100123 |
| 0123 | 123 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jofAAwyR)

Answer (score 0):

In case it is useful for someone, I got it finally like this below:

```
SELECT A.locid , A.CREATEDAT, B.LOCID2, B.CREATEDAT
from (
select locid, createdat
from tableName
where locid like '1%'
--and LENGTH(LOCID) == 10
and regexp_like( LOCID, '^[[:digit:]]*$')
and locstatus != 'DELETED' 
) AS A
INNER JOIN (
select TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM LOCID) AS LOCID2, createdat 
from tableName
where locid like '0%'
and regexp_like( LOCID, '^[[:digit:]]*$')
--and LENGTH(LOCID) == 10
and locstatus != 'DELETED'
) AS B
ON A.locid = B.LOCID2
```